# A question on the image of a Möbius function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a\in\mathbb C$ such that $|a|<1$ and consider the Möbius function
$$
f(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}
$$
I ask to show that if $|z|=1$, then $|f(z)|=1$ and if $|z|<1$, then $|f(z)|<1$ using the **maximum modulus theorem**.

I noticed that
$$
|1-\bar{a}z|^2-|z-\bar{a}|^2=
1+|a|^2|z|^2-2Re(\bar{a}z)-(|z|^2-2Re(z\bar{a})+|a|^2)
=(1-|a|^2)(1-|z|^2)
$$
Consequently, if $|z|=1$, then $|f(z)|=1$ and if $|z|<1$, then $|f(z)|<1$. This is quite straightforward. Is there an easy way to prove that using the maximum modulus theorem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are specifically asked to use MMP you can do the following: Let $|z|=1$. Then $|z-a|=|\overline {z-a}|=|\frac1 z-\overline a|=|1-\overline a z|$ so $|f(z)|=1$. MMP implies that $|f(z) | <1$ for $|z|<1$ since $f$ is analytic and not a constant.

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama